# Render ascx control with parameter and insert html in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ascx

How can i replace a ascx control to a string tag in html ?

I want to create a dynamic html template.

This is my html

```
<div id="Detail_Container">

   <div>Gallery 1</div>

    <load_gallery>G6</load_gallery>

   <div>Gallery 2</div>

   <load_gallery>G7</load_gallery>

</div>
```

I tryied this :
Control is rendering but my images doesnt load into the control.

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
            UserControl objControl = (UserControl)LoadControl(inControlPath);
            objControl.GalleryId = "G5";

            if (objControl != null)
                objControl.RenderControl(textWriter);

            string controlstr = tw.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not just add usercontrol as string to html because it's rendered and processed on server. But you can place a placeholder on your page and then add control to this palaceholder.

Here is sample code how you can load and add usercontrol at runtime:

```
  //here I am loading usercontrol from ascx file...
  WfGenericFormUserControl genControl = (WfGenericFormUserControl)LoadControl("~/UserControls/WfGenericFormUserControl.ascx");

  //FormPlaceHolder is placeholder inside target page
  FormPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(genControl);
```

GenControl control will now be shown on the page.

Comment: yes but how can add this placeholder correct point dinamically ? I mean can i replace "<load_gallery>G6</load_gallery>" with formplaceholder ?

Comment: Yes you can produce all html code at runtime and then use following command for injecting inside your placeholder: placeholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='myclass'>some html produced at runtime</div>"));